# MBR or GPT for external backup drive

Tags: partitioning, mbr, gpt

I bought an external 1 TB hard drive for backups but I am not sure whether to use MBR or GPT. I am using Linux (x86_64) with MBR/BIOS but my laptop supports GPT/UEFI. I know about the differences between MBR and GPT, but is there any reason to choose GPT over MBR, like the cyclic redundancy check (CRC) values to see if data is intact and if the data is corrupted to move the data to undamaged areas? Will this have any difference for an external backup drive?

Comment: It really doesn't matter with an external drive.  The majority of limitations surrounding MBR are associated with the disk the system partition itself is located on.  At least in the context of Windows.

Comment: What file system are you going to put on the drive, and is the drive only going to be used by this system?  I would suggest that a limitation of the filesystem would lead you to choose MBR or GPT.  MBR is limited to 2TB, but your disk is under that limit.  Beyond that, I agree with @Ramhound, since Linux can read either.

Comment: As I am going to use it only on Linux machines I will be going for ext4.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

GPT is much more resilient against data corruption because of the CRC
and because it stores multiple copies of the partitioning and boot data,
so recovery is still possible after a catastrophic data failure.

Also, GPT has a "protective MBR", so the GPT disk still looks like MBR
to older software.
As your disk is 1 TB, and as MBR can support up to 2 TB, even though
formatted as GPT, the entire disk will be usable as both MBR and GPT.

Therefore you can use either format, except that GPT may better conserve
your data.